# Workflow not getting started in SP library

Tags: sharepoint-2013

We have a SharePoint Approval workflow which is supposed to start whenever anyone publishes a file in SP library.

It works fine when users publish one file at a time.

However, when multiple files are published together the workflow is not initiated.These files are published from top menu -> Files -> Check In -> Publish as Major version

I found this article and think it might have to do something with one of these settings. 
http://www.sharepointfire.com/2015/04/increase-sharepoint-workflow-performance-and-reliability/

We are not initiating more than 15 workflows at a time so I don’t think it throttle size but might be something else.

I am still clueless on what setting needs to be changed, before I make that change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using builtin Sharepoint 2010 approval workflows or is it a custom approval workflow made with Sharepoint 2013 and Workflow Manager?

Comment: it's the same issue with both types. I tried with both custom and SP approval workflow, but experienced the same problem that workflow was not getting initiated when multiple files are checked in.